# What Changed with Shimano Hyperglide-C?

Tags: hub, cassette

Shimano's HyperGlide-C (11-speed), are the hubs backwards compatible?
Can I put an 8/9/10-speed cassette on a Hyperglide-C hub?
Can I put a Hyperglide-C cassette on a Hyperglide hub?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Sheldon Brown](http://sheldonbrown.com/k7.html#hyperdrivec) to the rescue: "Shimano uses the trademark "Hyperglide-C" to designate a system with an 11 tooth sprocket. The "C" stands for "compact". These systems are used with smaller-than-usual chainwheel sizes, or on bicycles that have a small drive wheel, or to achieve higher gears.

Due to clearance problems, the cutaway between the splines on 11-tooth sprockets only goes halfway through the sprocket. The matching splines on Hyperglide-C bodies don't go all the way to the outer end of the body."

To summarize: Hyperglide-C cassette on non-hyperglide C body gives wobbles (which you can correct with a 1 mm spacer).

In the [reverse case](http://www.cyclingforums.com/t/383325/hyperglide-cassette-on-hyperglide-c-freehub-body), you can remove some spacers from your cassette (if you have them) to get it to fit (though I'm not really sure when this case would practically occur).

Comment: From reading your second link it seems like I have a fundamental misconception. Hyperglide-C is the 11-speed standard, right? Why is this guy asking: "I've got a worn 7-speed Hyperglide-C cassette?"

Comment: Seems like a typo - he corrects it later in the same paragraph and in the second post of his in the thread.